# How do I center my links within my drop down menu (another inquiry inside)?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip1gi.png

I would like to center the links in the sub menu (pictured above) and make the highlighted area (the light purple) fill 100% of the width of the sub menu (hover effect).

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="home.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Logos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Signatures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wallpapers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* HEADER */

.header {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

img.logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

ul.menu {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.menu li  {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

ul.menu li a {
    padding: 19px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #888888;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.menu li:hover a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: #5b2371;
}

ul.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #5b2371;
    width: 91px;
}

ul.submenu li a {
    padding: 13px;
    color: #dddddd;
}

ul.menu li:hover > ul.submenu {
    visibility: visible; 
}

ul.submenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #7141bf;
}
```

Comment: What *specifically* have you tried so far that hasn't worked? What have you researched in order to solve this problem?

Comment: I thought that making the sub menu links a block element would help with the hover effect. I've tried line-height, vertical align, etc., for the other issue. I've Googled around. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats easy...

your `li`'s are not the same `width` as `ul`. just set `li` `width` to `100%`

and than add a `text-align: center;` to it and this will solve your problem :D

```
ul.submenu li {
    width:      100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

see **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/79cLC/)**

**EDIT:**

of course to get a clean menu you have to give the links `a` a 100% width too.

```
ul.submenu li a {
    padding: 13px;
    color:   #dddddd;
    width:   100%;   /* this one here to have a nice looking menu */
}
```

Comment: @Ruzzio no problem. you may vote up my answere if it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to center the li text, and then set the width of sub menu  element. This will fill the lighter purple sub menu background color.

```
ul.submenu li a {
padding: 13px;
color: #dddddd;
min-width:70px;}
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtruty/Kh3m8/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/P89wZ/1/

1. ul.menu li needed a text-align value of "center", which I added.
2. I removed width: 91px from ul.submenu
3. ul.submenu li a needed width:70px (or whatever value you want there, you can play around with it and decide what you like better).

   ```
   ul.menu li {
       display: inline-block;
       position: relative;
       text-align:center;
   }

   ul.submenu {
       visibility: hidden;
       position: absolute;
       background-color: #5b2371;
   }

   ul.submenu li a {
       padding: 13px;
       color: #dddddd;
       min-width:70px;
   }
   ```

Enjoy!